# getting "reactnativenavigationtest" signin error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

whenever I try to run, I get

error: Signing for "ReactNativeNavigationTests" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. (in target 'ReactNativeNavigationTests')

I am signed in as my development team in xcode..
what do I need to do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the picture below shows what solved my problem:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what you did to make it work? My page looks the same as yours.

Comment: oh wow what I did was I created a new react native project and copied everything to it. That also works if you're having a problem

Answer (score 0):

Go into `Libraries > ReactNativeNavigation.xcodeproj`, right click the `ReactNativeNavigationTests` target under `Targets` in the right pane, and hit `Delete`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed it was to click on my project on the top left, go to Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries and remove (-) "libReactNativeNavigationTests.a".

It will probably affect running tests with this library but it was not an issue for me then.